# How can I generate 4-week ranges of dates?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have to generate date range for 1 year in gap of 4 weeks ( or 28 days ) from a fixed date backward and going forward. For example I have DATE '2016-02-20'. I need to generate the below.

Start date = Sunday , End-date = Saturday

```
No   Start_date  End_date
==== =========  =======
1   1/24/2016   2/20/2016
2   12/27/2015  1/23/2016
3   11/29/2015  12/26/2015
4   .....
13  2/22/2015   3/21/2015
14  1/25/2015   2/21/2015
```

But,when 03/20/2016(Sunday) comes,it should **add**
`1. 2/21/2016   3/19/2016` & **remove** `14. 1/25/2015 2/21/2015`
and so on after every 4 weeks.

I have written the below, but I need help to iterate in minimal code( if possible.)

```
SELECT LEVEL,
  DATE '2016-02-20'-27*LEVEL-LEVEL+1 AS start_date,
  DATE '2016-02-20'-28*(LEVEL-1) AS end_date
FROM DUAL
Connect BY LEVEL < 15;
```

Comment: What is wrong with the core you have now - what output does it get? Or does it error?

Comment: @alex-poole It just generates for 1 year, but going forward after every 4th weeks from 2/20/16 , on Sunday the query should automatically remove one date range ( 25/2015 2/21/2015 )and add another (2/21/2016   3/19/2016)

Comment: What do you mean by going forward - you want to base it on the current date rather that a fixed date? If so how do you know that the period end date for today should be 2016-02-20? Or do you want a year in the future as well as a year in the past?

Comment: @AlexPoole The output is shown in  my question and there is no error ,but I need to add something more to the query to generate the dates going forward

Comment: @AlexPoole I have to take 2/20/2016 as the base and add 4 weeks , then that new date as the base and add 4 weeks and so on..At the same time remove one date range which is falling off the 1 year limit

Comment: But unless you are hard-coding the new base date, how do you know which period you are in?

Comment: @AlexPoole Hmm..can't we keep generating based on 2/20/2016 something like If MOD(TRUNC(SYSDATE) - DATE '2016-02-20',28) = 0 Then thats the new base date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want to have a rolling window of a year's worth of four-week ranges, based from the current date. To do that you need a fixed known period start (or end) date you can work from. Picking one that happens to be January 1st you can do:

```
SELECT DATE '2012-01-01' + (28 * (LEVEL - 1)) AS start_date,
  DATE '2012-01-01' + (28 * LEVEL) - 1 AS end_date
FROM DUAL
CONNECT BY DATE '2012-01-01' + (28 * LEVEL) - 1 <= TRUNC(sysdate)
```

Which will find 54 periods up to today. On March 21st it will find 55 periods, etc. You only want those that are in the last year, so use that as an inline view and restrict the range:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY start_date DESC) AS no, start_date, end_date
FROM (
  SELECT DATE '2012-01-01' + (28 * (LEVEL - 1)) AS start_date,
    DATE '2012-01-01' + (28 * LEVEL) - 1 AS end_date
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY DATE '2012-01-01' + (28 * LEVEL) - 1 <= TRUNC(sysdate)
)
WHERE end_date >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(sysdate), -12)
ORDER BY start_date DESC;

        NO START_DATE END_DATE 
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 01/24/2016 02/20/2016
         2 12/27/2015 01/23/2016
         3 11/29/2015 12/26/2015
...
        11 04/19/2015 05/16/2015
        12 03/22/2015 04/18/2015
        13 02/22/2015 03/21/2015
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` just generates your `NO` column, as the `LEVEL` is now in the wrong order.

If you always want exactly 14 rows in the result set you can move the `ROW_NUMBER()` into the inline view:

```
SELECT no, start_date, end_date
FROM (
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LEVEL DESC) AS no,
    DATE '2012-01-01' + (28 * (LEVEL - 1)) AS start_date,
    DATE '2012-01-01' + (28 * LEVEL) - 1 AS end_date
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY DATE '2012-01-01' + (28 * LEVEL) - 1 <= TRUNC(sysdate)
)
WHERE no <= 14
ORDER BY no;

        NO START_DATE END_DATE 
---------- ---------- ----------
         1 01/24/2016 02/20/2016
         2 12/27/2015 01/23/2016
         3 11/29/2015 12/26/2015
...
        12 03/22/2015 04/18/2015
        13 02/22/2015 03/21/2015
        14 01/25/2015 02/21/2015

 14 rows selected
```

Comment: Awesome! it works great! and gives me all 14 rows when I replace trunc(sysdate) to 3/20/16, but as of sysdate its giving only 13 rows.

Comment: Do you always want 14 rows? 13 covers 364 days so maybe you do.

Comment: Yes Sir, I would actually want 14 rows always.It gives perfect 14 rows on 3/20 , 4/17 ...but for other dates also it should give 14

Comment: I highly  appreciate your timely help and patience to understand my requirement!.You are too good!!

Comment: OK, added a variation that always gets 14 rows. Hope that helps.

Comment: Cool!! :-) Wonderful short and crisp. Spiffy!

Comment: I wanted to contact you regarding XML. I'm new to XML and wanted your guidance regarding Question: 35782907. Whenever you have time, you can reply me. Thanks again Sir!